# Implementing merge sort on a list of words - original words appended back to list?

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

I'm trying to implement the merge sort algorithm on a list of strings of size `N`, and I've managed to get it to sort, but for some reason the original values are being added onto the end of the sorted list.

I'm quite new to implementing sorting algorithms (read: very new), so would really appreciate anyone letting me know if I've missed something.

```
    public static void mergeSortWords(int n, List<String> words) {

        if (n < 2) {
            return;
        }

        int mid = n / 2; // Getting the mid-point of the array

        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(mid); // Left side of array
        List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>(n-mid); // Right side of array

        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            l.add(i, words.get(i));
        }

        for (int j = mid; j < n; j++) {
            r.add(j - mid, words.get(j));
        }


        mergeSortWords(mid, l); // recursively sort the left side
        mergeSortWords(n-mid, r); // recursively sort the right side

        mergeWords(n, words, l, r, mid, n-mid); // merge the sorted arrays back together
    }

    public static void mergeWords(int n, List<String> words, List<String> l, List<String> r, int left, int right) {

        if (words.size() > n) {
            return;
        }

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        while (i < left && j < right) {

            if (l.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(r.get(j)) < 0) { // comparing the strings alphabetically
                words.add(k++, l.get(i++));
            }
            else {
                words.add(k++, r.get(j++));
            }
        }

        while (i < left) {
            words.add(k++, l.get(i++));
        }
        while (j < right) {
            words.add(k++, r.get(j++));
        }
    }
```

I unit tested like so:

```
    @Test
    public void mergeSortWordsTest() {

        List<String> actual = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> expected = new ArrayList<String>();

        actual.add("hello");
        actual.add("yo");
        actual.add("hi");
        actual.add("what");
        actual.add("bottle");

        expected.add("bottle");
        expected.add("hello");
        expected.add("hi");
        expected.add("what");
        expected.add("yo");

        mergeSortWords(actual.size(), actual);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

And I receive:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :[bottle, hello, hi, what, yo]
Actual   :[bottle, hello, hi, what, yo, hello, yo, hi, what, bottle]
```

Thank you for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `words` list you pass to `mergeWords` is never cleared. `mergeWords` will just add new elements to this list without caring about the elements that it already contains. Simply do a

```
words.clear();
```

at the beginning of `mergeWords`.

Alternatively, you can overwrite the existing elements with `.set(int index, E element)` instead of `.add()`. But you need to make sure that the list is of the correct size.

A few unrelated comments:

In your function calls, you are always passing the size of the lists as an additional parameter (`n`, `left`, `right`). This is redundant (you can get the size with `list.size()`). Anything that is redundant can easily become inconsistent (i.e., what happens if you pass a wrong size?). So it is better to remove those parameters.

When you add an element to a list, you use the overload `add(int index, E element)`. This is perfectly fine, but I think using the overload `add(E element)` is much easier to handle as you don't need to keep track of where to add the elements. The overload will just append the new element to the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you so much, Nico! That worked. I thought it was something like that, so I tried making an empty list to pass in to add the elements from left and right back in, but it wasn't being sorted for some reason. But that's done the trick!